# Method/pattern to check for objects and place them as nested objects if criteria met

Tags: javascript, json

I have an account object with children accounts (rootAccount). I am trying to write some logic that will take the rootAccount object and search the children accounts to see if they are parents of any accounts. If so, then those accounts will be added to the children account in a new property for the account called children. It becomes a little more complex because each new account can possibly have child accounts and likewise be added as a new property to the account. So this will keep nesting objects possibly until there are no more children accounts.

Is there a common pattern/method to use for this scenario? I can get about as far as filtering out the object that is the parent but I'm not sure how to add it to the rootAccount object and then loop this logic so it will check for new children accounts and keep adding nested children accounts.

```
   var childAccount = [{Name: "Johnson Little Plastics", Id: '4', parentAccount: '3'}];


   var rootAccount = {
     Name: "Johnson Holding Company",
     Id: '1',
     children: [
       {Name: "Johnson Metals", Id: '2', parentAccount: '1'},
       {Name: "Johnson Plastics", Id: '3', parentAccount: '1'}
       ]
     }


     for(var x of childAccount){
         var f = rootAccount.children.filter((account,i) => {
         return account.Id == x.parentAccount;
     });

     console.log(f[0].Id);
     }
```

What it will look like after it runs through:

```
   var rootAccount = {
     Name: "Johnson Holding Company",
     Id: '1',
     children: [
       {Name: "Johnson Metals", Id: '2', parentAccount: '1'},
       {Name: "Johnson Plastics", Id: '3', parentAccount: '1',
        children: [{Name: "Johnson Little Plastics", Id: '4', parentAccount: '3'}]
       }
       ]
     }
```